# Сортировка в классе по заданному полю

Tags: java, сортировка

к сути вопроса: существует иерархия классов. Класс `Table`, класс `Rows`, класс  `Handler`; таблица состоит из строк, в классе `Handler` можно создавать неограниченное количество таблиц и строк в них (при создании строки можно выбрать в какую таблицу добавить эту строку). Я хотел бы реализовать сортировку строк некоторой таблицы (пользователь выбирает номер таблицы), по номеру строки (фактически по полю, так как "номер строки" - поле класса `Rows`). Я пробовал следующий способ:

```java
public class Rows implements Comparable {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rows rows){
        return Integer.compare(this.number, rows.getNumber());
    }
}
```

И после в классе `Table`

```java
    public void sortRowsByNum() {
        Collections.sort(rowsArrayList);
    }
```

Но я получил ошибку о том, что в суперклассе нет метода, чтобы я мог использоввать оверрайд. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то иные решения для моей задачи, заранее благодарю за любую помощь.
Весь код прилагаю ниже.

**Класс "Rows"**

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Rows {
    private int number; // номер строки
    private String data; // содержимое строки
    private int numT;

    public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number;}
    public void setData(String data) { this.data = data; }

    public int getNumber() { return number; }
    public String getData() { return data; }

    public Rows() {
        number = 0;
        data = "Some input text";
    }

    public Rows(int number, String data, @NotNull Table table) {
        this.number = number;
        this.data = data;
        this.numT = table.getNum();
    }

    public void printRows() { 
        System.out.print(number + ": " + data + "\n"); 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + ": " + data + "\n";
    }
}
```

**Класс "Table"**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Table {

    private int num;
    protected ArrayList<Rows> rowsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Table() { num = 0; }
    public Table(int num) { this.num = num; }

    public void setNum(int num) { this.num = num;}
    public int getNum() { return num; }

    public void sortRowsByNum() {
        // сортировка по номеру строки (перому полю из класса "Rows")
    }

    public void printTables() {
        System.out.print("Name: " + num);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(num);
    }
}
```

**Класс-обработчик "Handler"**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Handler {

    ArrayList<Table> listT = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Rows> listR = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Rows rows;
    Table table;

    public void printT() {
        for (Table table: listT) {
            System.out.print(table.toString());
            System.out.print(table.rowsArrayList.toString());
        }
    }

    public void createTable() {
        int numT;
        if (console.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Write the number of the Table");
            numT = console.nextInt();

            table = new Table(numT);
            listT.add(listT.size(), table);
        }
        else System.out.print("Please input integer value!\n");
    }

    public void createRows() {
        int numR, numT;
        String data;

        System.out.println("Write the number of the rows");

        if (console.hasNextInt()) {
            numR = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter any data");
            data = console.next();

            System.out.println("Chose Table: ");
            printT();
            if (console.hasNextInt()) {
                numT = console.nextInt();
                rows = new Rows(numR, data, listT.get(numT - 1));
                listT.get(numT - 1)
                     .rowsArrayList.add(
                         listT.get(numT - 1)
                              .rowsArrayList.size(), 
                         rows
                     );
            }
            else System.out.print("Please input integer value (number of table)!\n");
        }
        else System.out.print("Please input integer value (number of rows)!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде класс `Rows` НЕ реализует интерфейс `Comparable` и нигде не используется интерфейс `Comparator`, каким образом должна выполняться сортировка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс `Comparable` является обобщённым, и при его реализации следует указывать класс, экземпляры которого будут сравниваться, в вашем случае это:

```java
public class Rows implements Comparable<Rows> {
/*
... остальной код
*/
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rows rows){
        return Integer.compare(this.number, rows.getNumber());
    }
}
```

При такой реализации можно использовать метод сортировки [`Collections.sort(List<T extends Comparable> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Или же можно было отсортировать список строк при помощи компаратора:

```java
public void sortRowsByNum() {
    rowsArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Rows::getNumber));
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за предоставленное решение и за то, что сверх этого объяснили почему не работал способ с имплементированием!